# Does Castle Automatic Transaction Management create TransactionScope for Transactional methods?

Tags: .net, wcf, nhibernate, transactionscope, castle

I've got an app which should access its DB (via NHibernate) and perform web service calls (via WCF) in a single distributed transaction (which is propagated to called web services via WS-AT). For now I explicitly create TransactionScope and then open NHibernate sessions and perform WCF calls inside. Can I make Castle ATM create TransactionScope for me (or by any other means make WCF aware of the current transaction) or is it only able to manage NHibernate transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm the author of that service.

Version 3 which is currently in beta (the IO-bits are alpha, transactions are GA), sets the so called 'ambient transaction' - this is what TransactionScope is using behind the scenes.

This means that your transaction will flow across service boundaries.

The best way to get version 3 is by `install-package castle.services.transaction` and `castle.facilities.autotx`